Google API flow and google api client error
Code:
from google.auth.oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

Error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth.oauthlib'

I have tried
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

I have also tried
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib


The google modules have a bit different names
pip install google-api-python-client
unfortunately you can't use pip search from the command line anymore but you can use your browser https://pypi.org/search/?q=
and start your search with "google" or "google-auth"
this can be used for any other missing package
